# Bootstrap datetime picker doesn't collapse

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add date time picker for my mvc 5 application. tried several ways to do it.But it doesn't work.Text box and calender icon is appeared on the view but when i click on the calender it doesn't collapse and show the calender.. why is that?

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="container">
    <form action="" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Test</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="dtp_input1" class="col-md-2 control-label">DateTime Picking</label>
                <div class="input-group date form_datetime col-md-5" data-date="1979-09-16T05:25:07Z" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy - HH:ii p" data-link-field="dtp_input1">
                    <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span></span>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="dtp_input1" value="" /><br />
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>




<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
        //language:  'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn: 1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        forceParse: 0,
        showMeridian: 1
    });
    $('.form_date').datetimepicker({
        language: 'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn: 1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 2,
        minView: 2,
        forceParse: 0
    });
    $('.form_time').datetimepicker({
        language: 'fr',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn: 1,
        autoclose: 1,
        todayHighlight: 1,
        startView: 1,
        minView: 0,
        maxView: 1,
        forceParse: 0
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Installing/

**Minimal Requirements**

- jQuery
- *Moment.js*
- Bootstrap.js (transition and collapse are required if you're not using the full Bootstrap)
- Bootstrap Datepicker script
- Bootstrap CSS
- Bootstrap Datepicker CSS
- Locales:Moment's locale files

---

I create [simple demo](https://jsfiddle.net/y5zxah9b/) with your code and get error in console :

> Uncaught bootstrap-datetimepicker requires Moment.js to be loaded
>   first

So just add `Moment.js` to your app

Comment: still having the problem

Comment: @ThilinaDeSilva, could you open developer console and check what exactly problem?